# How can I sync a script on many servers without the need to manually pull, like you would do with git?

Tags: node.js, version-control

Currently, I have 6 servers which are running nearly the same nodejs script, they only differ in the database credentials. I frequently make changes to that script and to deploy the changes to all servers, I need to ssh on to all of them and pull all the changes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: 1 file-server can do it. To install push updates is very tedious.

Comment: @AjAX. could you elaborate a bit more? I just googled for fileserver, but couldn't find anything which would fix my problem.

Comment: On the 6 servers you just have a basic Node.js script running. Which gets all files from a single file-server. Use `require(IPaddress + '/file-path)`.

Comment: *`require(IPaddress + '/file-path')`.

Comment: Keep me up to date how it is going.